# Connect to local MySQL in App Engine with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine

I am testing the new App Engine PHP SDK (development environment) and have a problem connecting to my local MySQL.

I start the dev_appserver.py with the necessary paramters telling it where my MySQL is (--mysql_host=localhost --mysql_port=3306 --mysql_user=admin --mysql_password=password but still it's impossible to make a connection using the mysqli_connect command from the PHP script.

Somewhere I read that, with these commands, even a connection to cloudSQL should be routed...

Any suggestions what to look at next?

Ben

Answer (score 2):

Your development server probably is looking in the wrong location for the socket file. Look for a file mysql.sock

Common places are:

```
/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
or /tmp/mysql.sock
or /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Set up a symbolic link if you don't want to move anything or just connect to the socket directly:

```
$con = mysql_connect(':/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', 'root', '1234');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are testing it on a dev environment then you can simply ignore the cloudSQL routing now.

I believe you need to do the following Verify you can connect with simple MySQL connect function and then make sure MySQLi is installed (Since on the web installation steps of Google App Engine that was not included)

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', 'password');
if(!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}else{
   mysql_close($link);
   echo 'Connected successfully and everything seems fine .... Checking MySQLi Installation<br><br>';
   if(function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
     echo 'MySQLi is Installed :S';
   }else{
     echo 'Oops. You need to reconfigure Your PHP Installation to Include MySQLi';
   }
}
```

If you get a response like:

Connected successfully and everything seems fine .... Checking MySQLi Installation

Oops. You need to reconfigure Your PHP Installation to Include MySQLi

Then you may need to re-run the configuration to enable MySQLi & PDO drivers

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/installdir --enable-bcmath --with-mysql --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli
```